# td doesn't work width:100%

Tags: html, css, email

I have a `table` with 2 `tr`, they are wrapped properly but I wonder why the last tr's `td` (id TD_16) but doesn't allow width 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/va1p6w83/

Ignore the images. FYI, I'm doing email html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<td id="TD_16" colspan="2">`

Your table's previous rows had 2 columns. If you want a cell to be wider than the other columns, you'll need to set a `colspan` value

Answer (score 1):

```
<td id="TD_16" colspan=2">

</td>
```

Adding  colspan will  merge  cells.

Answer (score 0):

You should have reviewed previous TR. It is having two columns and as per Table view specification, you can not have two different rows with different columns without using colspan attribute.

Change the line and add colspan="2" as follow. You will have full width row. Also make sure your TD_16 style have width=100%

Answer (score 0):

Add `colspan` to your last tr's `td`. Check it [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) on how to use.

```
<tr id="TR_15">
    <td id="TD_16" colspan="2"> / spans 2 Column
        <span id="SPAN_17">Check out the informative video here for everything you need to know about the program.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```